# Magento 2.1 env.php failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: magento2, permission-denied

I am trying to install Magento 2 on my dedicated server from Bluehost company.
i have installed magento 2.1 using Command line and i have faced alot of file permissions issue.

i solved them all referring to : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

But still i am facing Permission denied.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: include(/home/mydomain/public_html/app/etc/env.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/mydomain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig/Reader.php

i tried to give chmod 777 and still the same.

Answer (score 0):

As per your explanation, you facing **ownership** and **Group** issue. please change the ownership of file as well as folder.

For change owner and group you can use below command.

```
chown -R user:group folder_name
```

before change user and group you have to check which user have permission to read the file and folder.